# How to write WordPress if_user_login

Tags: php, wordpress

I am fairly new to WordPress and php and I am trying to show different links based on if the user is logged in or not

How can I make below code to work?

```
<?php 
$new_post = $redux_demo['new_post'];
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    <a href="<?php echo $new_post; ?>" ><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i><?php echo $header_post_btn; ?></a>
?>
<?php } else {
    <a href="/contact" ><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i><?php echo $header_post_btn; ?></a>
?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP code should not be mixed with HTML code within the `<?php ?>` tag.

```
<?php
    $new_post = $redux_demo['new_post'];
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
?>
    <a href="<?php echo $new_post; ?>" ><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i><?php echo $header_post_btn; ?></a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="/contact" ><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i><?php echo $header_post_btn; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```